# What is the correct setting for pandas.read_csv to read a very raw CSV file with first three numbers compiled into datetime.datetime object?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

To be more explicit, I have this type of data

```
2011,1,14, Orange  ,Buy,1500,
2011,1,19, Apple   ,Sell,1500,
2011,1,19, Banana  ,Buy,4000,
```

I am trying to read it directly into DataFrame with a columns=['date','fruit', 'trade','quantity'] shape like this.

```
print df_grocer.date
2011-01-14 16:00:00     
2011-01-19 16:00:00     
2011-01-19 16:00:00
```

and

```
print df_grocer.fruit
Orange 
Apple  
Banana
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**`pd.read_csv`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

> parse_dates : boolean or list of ints or names or list of lists or dict, default False
>
> - boolean. If True -> try parsing the index.
> - list of ints or names. e.g. If [1, 2, 3] -> try parsing columns 1, 2, 3 each as a separate date column.
> - list of lists. e.g. If ***[[1, 3]]*** -> combine columns 1 and 3 and parse as
>     a single date column.
> - dict, e.g. ***{‘foo’ : [1, 3]}*** -> parse columns 1, 3 as date and call result ‘foo’
>
> Note: A fast-path exists for iso8601-formatted dates.

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

txt = """2011,1,14, Orange  ,Buy,1500,
2011,1,19, Apple   ,Sell,1500,
2011,1,19, Banana  ,Buy,4000,"""

df = pd.read_csv(
    StringIO(txt),
    skipinitialspace=True,
    header=None,
    parse_dates=dict(date=[0, 1, 2]),
    usecols=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    names=['_', '_', '_', 'fruit', 'trade', 'quantity']
)


print(df)

        date     fruit trade  quantity
0 2011-01-14  Orange     Buy      1500
1 2011-01-19  Apple     Sell      1500
2 2011-01-19  Banana     Buy      4000
```